# crypto library not found in MinGW

Tags: c, windows, openssl, mingw

I have a `C` code that uses `openssl` and `crypto` to do `AES` encryption.
It compiles in linux without problem.
But in windows and with `MinGW` it gives:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm compiling using this:

```
gcc code.c -lcrypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Lc:\mingw\msys\1.0\local\lib
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but I think its better to use the '/' path separator with mingw programs. Avoids unexpected problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat odd:

```
gcc code.c -lcrypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Lc:\mingw\msys\1.0\local\lib
```

Try:

```
gcc code.c -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Lc:\mingw\msys\1.0\local\lib -lcrypto
```

OpenSSL installs itself into `/usr/local/ssl` by default, which means your library is usually `/usr/local/ssl/lib`. Did you change it? I'm not sure what that translates to under MinGW.

Perhaps you could provide a `ls` of `c:\mingw\msys\1.0\local\lib`. If the library is not there, try to find it with `find c:\mingw\msys\1.0\local -iname libcrypto.a` (or `libcrypto.so`).

Comment: Thanks; it was `c:\mingw\msys\1.0\local\lib` folder problem! changing it to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib\` fixed problem